# How to rearrange the columns inside dataframe by passing through parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below list

```
('EmpId', 'EMpName', 'Age', 'SerialNo')
```

I want to bring Age,SerialNo in the starting position and rest of the columns as follows

ColumnsToRearrange = ['Age', 'SerialNo']

By hard coding the columns inside dataframe i can achieve as below . Is there any possibility i can pass this as parameter

```
df = df[['Age', 'SerialNo'] + [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['Age', 'SerialNo']]]
```

But i want to pass this as a parameter

```
df = df[Header + [col for col in df.columns if col not in Header]]
```

i am getting below error message

```
Error:TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Comment: The problem is that you're concatenating tuples and lists. Work only with lists. For the rest you're approach is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So below are the Four Methods  by which you can reorder the columns of your DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'EmpId':[1,2,3,4],'EMpName':[2,4,6,8],'Age':[3,7,6,8],'SerialNo':[2,4,8,2]})
"""
    EmpId  EMpName  Age  SerialNo
        0      1        2    3         2
        1      2        4    7         4
        2      3        6    6         8
        3      4        8    8         2 
"""

 Original- ('EmpId', 'EMpName', 'Age', 'SerialNo')
 Output -  ('Age', 'SerialNo','EmpId', 'EMpName')
```

## Two column Swapping

```
cols = list(df.columns)
a, b = cols.index('EmpId'), cols.index('Age')
cols[b], cols[a] = cols[a], cols[b]
df = df[cols]
```

## Reorder column Swapping (2 swaps)

```
cols = list(df.columns)
a, b, c, d = cols.index('EmpId'), cols.index('Age'), cols.index('EMpName'), cols.index('SerialNo')
cols[a], cols[b], cols[c], cols[d] = cols[b], cols[a], cols[d], cols[c]
df = df[cols]
```

## Swapping Multiple Now it comes down to how you can play with list slices -

```
cols = list(df.columns)
colss = cols[2:] + cols[:2]
df = df[colss]
seq_list=['Age', 'SerialNo']
```

## Creating Function

```
def set_column_sequence(dataframe, seq, front=True):
    '''Takes a dataframe and a subsequence of its columns,
       returns dataframe with seq as first columns if "front" is True,
       and seq as last columns if "front" is False.
    '''
    cols = seq[:] # copy so we don't mutate seq
    for x in dataframe.columns:
        if x not in cols:
            if front: #we want "seq" to be in the front
                #so append current column to the end of the list
                cols.append(x)
            else:
                #we want "seq" to be last, so insert this
                #column in the front of the new column list
                #"cols" we are building:
                cols.insert(0, x)
    return dataframe[cols]
q=set_column_sequence(df,seq_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your tuple

```
('EmpId', 'EMpName', 'Age', 'SerialNo')
```

to a list

```
['EmpId', 'EMpName', 'Age', 'SerialNo']
```

Comment: Can i pass parameter in rearrange

Comment: @Ravi What is `Header`? Is it `('EmpId', 'EMpName', 'Age', 'SerialNo')`?